sublime IDE using wrong version of python
I'm running Sublime on linux.
I'm trying to import pygame in a file I'm working on. When I type import pygame, or any other module for that matter, I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame' as output.
I suspect this is due to sublime using the wrong version of python. During my quest to solve this, i realised that in my terminal, i have python 3.10.12 installed, but when i print sys.version in Sublime, i get 3.9.18.
I have tried following this tutorial to change it, but it didn't work. when i change my Python.sublime-build to python3.10 as stated in the tutorial, i get the error bash: line 1: python3.10: command not found. it only works with the Python.sublime-build set to python3, with which i have the wrong version of python.
any help would be greatly appreciated.
I have tried following that tutorial but to no avail. I have tried reinstalling python, reinstalling python3, installing python and python3 under the same name, but nothing works. I've looked at two or three other stackoverflow posts with very similar problems, but none of the given solutions work for me.

(linux assumed) check
~/.config/sublime-text/Packages/Python/Python.sublime-build
{
"cmd": ["python3.9", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]File "(...?)", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python",
....  , change to your desired version, i've tested on versions 3.9.5, 3.8

@ticktalk i have already tried that, that's exactly what was shown in the tutorial i tried. for me, it says  "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"] at the beginning of the file, and if i change that "python3" part to anything except "python3" or "python3.9", i get an error.

so, changing it DOES WORK !. at the command prompt, how do you invoke python3.10 (...) ? what does the command which python3.10 return , it could 'simply' be that the version you want is not on the path ($PATH) and needs to have the directory where python3.10 resides. finally, saying 'i get an error', but not showing the error is useless wrt getting help.

I have python3.11 installed under anaconda env, but this is not on my path !
see below the error thrown if I replace my python3 with python3.11 in the sublime config
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python3.11'
[cmd: ['python3.11', '-u', '/home/ticktalk/code/scratchpad/niles.py']]
[dir: /home/ticktalk/code/scratchpad]
[path: /home/ticktalk/.local/bin:/....]
[Finished]

i checked my python version in the terminal simply by running python3 and seeing what version is shown on startup.

@ticktalk i also already said what the error was. its in the original post, not in my comment, so i didn't mention it again.

Your post ... title - Sublime IDE using wrong version... then within your post something completely different  '...no module names 'pygame'. Can you get a version of python running from the command line that successfully imports pygame ? if so, then set that python version within your sublime config. if you still have issues then check that your PATH includes the correct paths to any modules required.  OR am I missing something .
